# React: CssBaseLine component doesn't update after Material UI theme changed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to update CssBaseline component whenever the theme was changed by button, but it didn't.
Whenever button is clicked, theme seemed to be changed, but what CssBaseline did hasn't been changed such as body's background color, etc.

Is there any way to change it?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import Title from './components/Title';
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from './libs/Theme';
import { MuiThemeProvider, CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core';


function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(darkTheme);

  const handleClick = () => {
    theme.palette.type === 'dark' ? setTheme(lightTheme) : setTheme(darkTheme);
  }

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleClick}>Change Theme</Button>
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Title />
      </Container>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

libs/Theme.js

```
import { createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core';

export const lightTheme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: 'light'
    }
  })
);

export const darkTheme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: 'dark'
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the work of `<React.StrictMode>`. Take those tags out and it should work. You can track this issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20708 for the bug and its possible resolution.

Note that this answer was written on MUI latest release `v4.11.0`

Comment: Thank you so much. You save the day!!!. It worked like a charm after I removed <React.StrictMode>

Comment: you are welcome. you can still opt to keep `StrictMode` for debugging purposes on a dev environment if you clone the theme object every time the state changes `theme={{...theme}}` - but take it off on production build